# twitter4j cordova plugin using for login

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

1. in my js file twitterLogin() method  used to call plugin  for
   twitter login and get twitter user name as result

   ```
       function twitterLogin(){
           cordova.exec(function(data) {       
               alert(data);        
           }, function(error) {
           }, "TwitterPlugin", "twitter", [  ]);   
       }


   i am new to android... cordova plugin using android twitter login after login twitter come twitterloginactivity but not come to
   ```

   onactivity result.below coding using for to call activity.in this
   code i am using twitter 4j android core jar

   - List item

     ```
     Intent intent = new Intent(cordova.getActivity(), TwitterLoginActivity.class);          
                 cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);
                 cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

     in this code using for login twitter in activity class .when i click login twitter button



                 requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                 this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
     ```

     after login sucess again call to twitter plugin not working

     ```
     Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                     if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                         // oAuth verifier
                         String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                         try {

                             AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

                             Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                             e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                             e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());

                             e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                             e.commit(); // save changes

                             long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                             User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                             String username = user.getName();
                             btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                             Intent i = new Intent();
                             i.putExtra("personName", username);
                             setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                             finish();
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user Name " + username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error  " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             // Check log for login errors
                             Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                         }
                     }
     ```